# Displaying full date with momentJs

Tags: momentjs

i want to have a format like this "Lundi , 11 Janvier 2016 , 12.45 " in moment
i have done this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    moment.locale('fr');
    moment().format("LLLL");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sdate').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
            timePicker: false,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            firstDay: 1
        });
    });

</script>
```

the month is in frensh and the shortname of the week " Lu Ma Me ..." all is ok but when i click the date to obtain the format in the top i have this "01/11/2016" . 
[image: in google chrome]

help plz .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your issue adding `format` option when you initialize the `daterangepicker`

```js
$('#sdate').daterangepicker({
    locale: { 
        format: 'LLLL'
    },
    singleDatePicker: true,
    timePicker: false
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/locale/fr.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type='text'id="sdate">
```

Comment: Thank you very much VINCENZOC